# Socket Programming (sys/socket.h)

Tags: c, sockets, websocket, ip, webserver

Looking at the generic socket struct defined [sys/socket.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) spec it lists:

```
sa_family_t   sa_family       address family
char          sa_data[]       socket address (variable-length data)
```

Looking at my actual header file located at /usr/includes/sys/socket.h on my linux machine, it is defined as the following.

```
 struct osockaddr
      {
        unsigned short int sa_family;
        unsigned char sa_data[14];
      };
```

Now I know if I include the  [netinet/in.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netinetin.h.html) it will define a `sockaddr_in`  structure and since I'm using `AF_INET` it would make since to use this...

```
struct sockaddr_in {
   short int            sin_family;
   unsigned short int   sin_port;
   struct in_addr       sin_addr;
   unsigned char        sin_zero[8];
};
```

However, I feel it is unnecessary to #include another lib (netinet/in.h) when I can simply use the generic `osockaddr` structure.

---

Now I understand my `osockaddr` member `sa_family` will relate to `AF_INET` but I'm unclear what actually goes inside the `sa_data` member... I'm assuming `port,addr,zero` in relation to the `sockaddr_in` structure, but I am unclear.

**Question:** Can anyone give me an example of what using the generic `osockaddr` structure looks like?

What I have so far....

```
#include<sys/socket.h>    
int main(void){
    struct osockaddr address;
    address.sa_family = AF_INET;
    address.sa_data = ? //What goes here (port, addr, zero)?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`netinet/in.h` is no *extra library*, it is just a sub-set of definitions part of the one library you are going to link against any way.

This generic address is like an abstract-base-Class. You are not supposed to create it. You only use it if you do not care about what kind of address you have or if you want to accept any kind of address.

Usage would look like this.

```
/* print any kind of socket address */
void prettyPrintAddress(struct sockaddr *addr) {
  switch (addr->sa_family) {
     case AF_INET:
       // Typocast to the actual type
       struct sockaddr_in *in_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)addr;
       // print [ipv4]:protocl:ipv4:port
       break;
     case AF_INET6:
       // Typocast to the actual type
       struct sockaddr_in6 *in6_addr = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)addr;
       // print [ipv6]:protocl:ipv6:port
       break;
     case AF_UNIX:
       // Typocast to the actual type
       struct sockaddr_un *un_addr = (struct sockaddr_un *)addr;
       // print [unix]:socket-path
       break;
     ...
  }
}

prettyPrintAddress(anyAddress);
prettyPrintAddress((struct sockaddr *) in_addr);
prettyPrintAddress((struct sockaddr *) in6_addr);
prettyPrintAddress((struct sockaddr *) un_addr);
```

Comment: I'm would be initializing and linking the entire `netinet/in.h` file so it is extra... and I'm not required to link against it,  `sys/socket.h` defines socket(),bind(),listen(),rec(),send() and works completely fine without it...

Comment: No, nothing is linked against header files. This is not Java or what ever language you come from. Both headers belong to the same standard library. `netinite/in.h` just tells you some features this library has. Not including it does not mean those features are not included. You could even use those features without including it.

Comment: Everything is linked.... If I don't `#include<netinet/in.h>` header file, I simply won't be able to use anything defined in that file "features"... the #include is a preprocessor directive for the compiler... if I don't #include that file I wont initialize anything inside of it thus making my program that more efficient...

Comment: No. The processor has nothing to do with linking. My observation is you have a totally wrong understanding of header files.

Comment: PRE-processor!!! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives

Comment: Read what a header file is, and what #include preprocessing directive does....https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html#Header-Files and I quote "Including a header file produces the same results as copying the header file into each source file that needs it" I don't want to copy the entire `netinent/in.h` header file into my program if I don't have to...

Comment: I do know C and I do know what the pre-processor does. If your are considered about compile-time, let me tell you: You don't even have to include sys/socket.h if you wont to use socket(),bind(), etc. But it won't Influence the performance/size of your program because those headers do not contain code, just definitions.

Comment: Please tell me how the hell my program will know what the socket(),bind(),etc function do if I don't include `sys/socket.h`?

Comment: and yes it will influence size and performance because not only does it add 621 lines of code to my program it's also initializing constants...

Comment: add `extern int socket (int, int,  int);` to your code and you can use socket. `extern int bind(int, void*, int);` for bind.

Comment: Write a `hello world` compile. check the binarys size. Add hundreds of constants. compile. compare size. No difference.  So lets end this here.

Comment: I don't even need to write a `hello world` program, what you are telling me is the the amount of lines a program contains doesn't influence the size of memory.... Do you even know what a program's stack looks like https://gabrieletolomei.wordpress.com/miscellanea/operating-systems/in-memory-layout/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90456/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-x539).

Comment: getting back to my question at hand... the generic `osockaddr` structure is "GENERIC" meaning it can be used for any of the socket struct types including the `AF_INET` or IP address family socket... so I'm simply looking for an example of using the `osockaddr` structure with the `AF_INET` or IP address family, do you know how?

Comment: "*how the hell my program will know what the socket(),bind(),etc function do* by calling the library code implementing what the headers prototype, with the latter being optional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.
you can think about `sockaddr` as a sort of union:

```
struct sockaddr
{
  short int sin_family;
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned short int   sin_port;
      struct in_addr       sin_addr;
      unsigned char        sin_zero[8];
    };
    unsigned char sa_data[14]
  };
};
```

so yea, if you take `sin_port`'s two bytes, minding the correct endianness, you can put them in `sa_data[0]` and `sa_data[1]`, then you can take `sin_addr`'s 4 bytes and put them in `sa_data[2]` to `sa_data[6]`.
But you really should not do that since it is extremely poor programming and it will make your code unreadable to anyone else, including yourself in 6 months.
If for some strange reason you don't want to `#include "netinet/in.h"` you can just define just this struct in your own code file and use it.

Comment: Why is it so "strange" to be using the standard `sys/socket.h` libs structs? was the lib not design for this exact purpose? and if it's such bad programming why is it a standard (and approved by the ISO)? if the lib is for sockets sys/socket.h and defines it's own structure... why would it be bad programming to use it? to me including and initializing another library to patch over sounds like bad programming....

Comment: `socket.h` is designed to support any type of socket. You want an IP socket so you need to use the standard struct for an IP socket which is in `netinet/in.h` (an integral part of the sockets library). `socket.h` doesn't include all structs for all types of sockets since there are lots of them and you can define your own as well. `sockaddr` is not meant to be instantiated on its own, its just a placeholder, it's the C equaivalent of C++ abstract base class.

Comment: Yea exactly the generic socket struct `osockaddr` can support any type of struct, so I'm simply looking for use with `AF_INET` family... your answer pretty much above defined it for me, using two bytes for port, 4 bytes addr in the `sa_data` knowing that I have an IPv4 address and knowing what port I'm going to bind it to I can change the sa_data[14] length accordingly. Yes I know this isn't the "portable" solution because there could be an IPv6 address which would change the length... but I know its an IPv4.

Comment: I understand the `netinet/in.h` is a "integral" part of the sockets lib and I agree with you, but its not a "required" part of the sockets lib, and so my question was basically how would that look... defining the IPv4 address and a port in the sa_data[] without adding the netinet/in.h structs...

Comment: IPv6 would have a different `sin_family`. My reasoning is strictly in the realm of "don't make other people who need to read your code want to hit you with a baseball bat" which is what I would want to do, had I seen such code.

Comment: Haha "hit you with a baseball bat" yea I know what you mean, but I'll be the only one using it for now... Take a look a Beej's guide http://beej.us/net2/html/structs.html  and when he says, "This is rather unwieldy since you don't want to tediously pack the address in the sa_data by hand" this is what I mean... I want to tediously pack the address in the `sa_data` by hand.